# Clean up Ruby versions and gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, bundle

I really need your expertise on this one. I'm new to Ruby and gems and messed up my computer settings. I got it roughly to work but after doing more gem installs today, I decided it was time to fix my Ruby and gems once and for all.

I use RVM.

Under:

```
/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems
```

I see:

```
cache
ruby-1.9.2-p320
ruby-1.9.3-p448
ruby-1.9.3-p448@global
ruby-2.0.0-p247
ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
```

But when I do `rvm list` it only sees one Ruby:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
```

I suspect I messed up my Ruby install when I tried hacking it together because:
1. RVM is obviously inconsistent with the many versions of Ruby I see above. 
2. I got an error of "permission denied" when just doing `bundle install`:

```
    Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/build_info/coffee-script-source-1.6.3.info
    An error occurred while installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Which, from other Stack Overflow posts, seems to hint I installed Ruby and gems wrong, and messed up sudoing stuff I shouldn't.

Here's my `$PATH` output for reference:

```
/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Jonathan/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools
```

I assume when I use `gem install`, it installs it to ~/.rvm/gems/version-of-ruby-rvm-is-currently-using/
but I'm not sure, and not sure if each of those directories is also a gemset.

I'm pretty lost.

Thanks so much for the help!

Update running rvm info:

```
$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.3-p448:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin unknown7cd1c3db60f7 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.8/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.12 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "2 months 2 days 14 hours 12 minutes 30 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p448"
    date:         "2013-06-27"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin12.5.0"
    patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41675"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448"
    ruby:         "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Jonathan/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448:/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Have you tried `rvm implode` (and maybe `sudo rvm implode` as well)?

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question. It tells us all the important information about what it knows.